# RSpec Capybara Element at X no longer present in the DOM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a RSpec test with this:

`within all('tr')[1] do
 expect(page).to have_content 'Title'
 expect(page).to have_content 'Sub Title'
end`

And it's failing at `expect(page).to have_content 'Title'` with the following error message:

`Element at 54 no longer present in the DOM`

I have not been able to find the exact meaning of what this error message means and this test is flakey, sometimes it passes, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other capybara finders, `all` doesn't really wait for elements to appear in the DOM.  So if your table is not fully loaded, it simply goes straight to the expectation within that block and could potentially fail.  That could easily explain why sometimes it fails and other times it succeeds.

I suggest using another expectation before this block and ensure that the table is fully loaded first.  I don't know what your DOM looks like, but you can try something like:

```
expect(page).to have_css('tr td', :count => 15)
```

So at this point, you've waited for 15 rows to show up in the DOM prior to moving onto your next steps.  Hope that helps.

Comment: #all doesn't wait by default, but can be made to --  there's also one other huge downside to using #all like this -- see my answer

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Tom!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer details, #all by default doesn't wait for elements to appear so it's possible you're not actually getting the elements you think you are.  Rather than the solution in the other answer, it is possible to make #all wait for elements to appear by specifying one of the :count, :minimum, :maximum, or :between options.

```
within all('tr', minimum: 10)[1] do
  ...
end
```

for instance.  This is all assuming that the action before the #within in your test isn't triggering an ajax action that is replacing existing rows in a table with other rows.  If row replacement is happening then you may be running into one of the biggest downsides of using #all -- when using #all the returned elements cannot automatically be re-queried if they leave the page and are replaced, since their entire query can't be stored with them (no index into the results).   In that case you're better off changing the code to

```
within find(:xpath, './/tr[2]') do
  ...
end
```

This way the element you're searching within can be reloaded automatically if needed